# Optimizing MySQL Query With MAX()

Tags: mysql, max

Apologies if this has been asked before but is there any way, at all, I can optimize this query to run faster. At the minute it takes about 2 seconds which while isn't a huge amount it is the slowest query on my site, all other queries take less that 0.5 secs.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS MAX(images.id) AS maxID, celebrity.* FROM images
JOIN celebrity ON images.celeb_id = celebrity.id
GROUP BY images.celeb_id
ORDER BY maxID DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

Here is an explain:

```
1 SIMPLE celebrity ALL PRIMARY NULL NULL NULL 536 Using temporary; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE images ref celeb_id celeb_id 4 celeborama_ignite.celebrity.id 191
```

I'm at a loss at how to improve the performance in this query further. I'm not super familiar with MySQL, but I do know that it is slow because I am sorting on the data created by MAX() and that has no index. I can't not sort on that as it gives me the results needed, but is there something else I can do to prevent it from slowing down the query?

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows does the `celebrity` table have?

Comment: The `celebrity` table has 536 rows but the `images` table has 103,411 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need fast solution - then don't perform such queries in runtime.

Just create additional field `last_image_id` in `celebrity` table and update it on event of uploading of new image (by trigger or your application logic, doesn't matter)

Comment: Haha. The simplest solutions are always the best I guess. Thanks, this is probably the best way to go, although I may have to use someone else's suggestion until I can implement the new field.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the latest image this way:

```
SElECT c.*, i.id AS image_id
FROM celebrity c
JOIN images i ON i.celeb_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN images i2 ON i2.celeb_id = c.id AND i2.id > i.id
WHERE i2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,20;
```

In other words, try to find a row `i2` for the same celebrity with a higher id than `i.id`.  If the outer join fails to find that match, then `i.id` must be the max image id for the given celebrity.

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS can cause queries to run extremely slowly.  I've found some cases where just removing the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS made the query run 200x faster (but it could also make only a small difference in other cases, it depends on the table, so you should test both ways).

If you need the equivalent of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, just run a separate query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM celebrity;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, but unfortunately newtover's query seems to run faster for me. In other cases SQL_CALC hasn't made much difference, but in this one it has, I've swapped to doing the pagination query separately & that has also improved the speed of things so thanks for that tip too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a compound index on `(celeb_id, id)` in table `images` (supposing it's a MyISAM table), so the `GROUP BY celeb_id` and `MAX(id)` can use this index.

But with big tables, you'll probably have to follow @zerkms' advice and add a new column in table `celebrity`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN *
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(id) as maxID, celeb_id as id
  FROM images
  GROUP BY celeb_id
  ORDER by maxID DESC
  LIMIT 0, 20) as ids
JOIN celebrity USING (id);
```

the query does not allow row number precalculation, but an additional:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT celeb_id)
FROM images;
```

or even (if each celebrity has an image):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM celebrity;
```

will not cost much, because can easily be cached by the query cache (if it not switched off).

Comment: InnoDB indexes already have the PK appended, so there's no need to add  id to the end of it.

Comment: @Bill, hm, it is useful to know!

Comment: This seems to be the fastest query for me. I get 0.24 secs average which is a lot faster than my 1.5-2 secs before. Precalc is only used for pagination so I can just split that into a separate query without any problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL doesn't perform so good with joins. i would recommend to dividing your query in two. that is in first query select the Celeb and then select image. Simply avoid joins.
Check out this link - http://phpadvent.org/2011/a-stitch-in-time-saves-nine-by-paul-jones

Comment: Sorry, but that's my experience with MySQL 5.3. and multiple queries really improves the performance.

Comment: There are times that splitting queries is simpler and easier to optimize.  But telling people a blanket rule like "simply avoid joins" is misleading.  It's like telling them that a `for` loop is inefficient because it just runs the same code over and over.

Comment: Agreed. I have had cases where I've needed to split queries, but not all joins are evil.

Comment: Advising to avoid Joins in a RDBMS is like telling people to drive cars but never change gears.